# Swift Error when calling selectRowAtIndexPath on tableview

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview, viewdidappear

I am trying to programmatically select a cell in a tableview.  I get a SIGABORT error when hitting the selectRowAtIndexPath.  myIndex has a value of 1.  I am calling this from a viewController that has implemented the required tableview delegate and datasource methods.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if myIndex != nil {
        self.myTableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(index: myIndex), animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Middle)
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure the cell is there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pay attention to error messages in console - they are very helpful most of the times. When you run your code you'll see message:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid index path for
>   use with UITableView.  Index paths passed to table view must contain
>   exactly two indices specifying the section and row.  Please use the
>   category on NSIndexPath in UITableView.h if possible.

Which describes both what the problem is and how to fix it - you should use different initializer for NSIndexPath

```
self.myTableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0), animated: false, scrollPosition: .Middle)
```

Comment: *Excellent* answer! I was about to post something similar, but I could not have explained it any better or more completely. (Voted.)

Comment: Thanks.  I just figured out how to show the ERROR console.  Is there a good tutorial on debugging and / or reading the error console?  Thanks

Comment: Sorry, can't point to good tutorials, may be this one will help - http://www.raywenderlich.com/28289/debugging-ios-apps-in-xcode-4-5.  You can also watch wwdc videos on debugging from previous years, there's tons of great insights in them

Answer (score 2):

selectRowAtIndexPath will want an indexPath with row and section. Not just an index.